# Custom Dimension Report and Sorting by Value

Tags: google-analytics

I've setup a custom dimension in Google Analytics called 'Publication' to track which publication an article has been sourced from. The data appears to be tracking, but I'm unable to sort via the value.

Here's an example of the tracking code on one page:

```
 ga('create', 'UA-XXX', 'auto');
 var dimensionValue = 'News Site';
 ga('set', 'dimension1', dimensionValue);
 ga('send', 'pageview');
```

And here's one on another, each is sending a different `dimensionValue` string.

```
 ga('create', 'UA-XXX', 'auto');
 var dimensionValue = 'Game Site';
 ga('set', 'dimension1', dimensionValue);
 ga('send', 'pageview');
```

If I look in Google Analytics though and create a custom report, the articles appear in the list, but I cannot sort via the value of the `dimensionValue` variable. I can't seem to find it in any of the drop-down menus. Ideally I want to see how many page views `News Site` gets vs `Game Site`. Does it take time for the values to appear? For some reason it shows a bunch of page info instead.

[image: Cannot find the value of dimensionValue]

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be a reporting question rather than a programming question so it is possibly OT, but you should be able to sort simply by clicking on the table header (works for me, an arrow to indicate the sort direction appears only after the first sort).

Comment: But the data that is appearing on the report is not consistent with what I'm sending to this dimension. It should only be getting strings like 'Game Site' and 'News Site' but instead it's getting full titles with dates such as `analysis:article - - 20161104 - with-second-fulbright-group,-us-maintains-arctic-research-focus` - Is there someway to filter these out?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the problem.  You are using a set call which affects all later calls to Google Analytics, so if dimensionValue is overwritten later in the page and there are subsequent tracking calls you might end up with wrong values. Is your site public ? This might be easier to solve after having a look at it. Else you might try to send the dimension directly with the pageview call (via a configuration object) and see if the wrong values disappear.

Comment: The site is public, the articles are here: http://arcticnow.com - I think *might* have figured out what is causing the issue. I'm using JSTL to filter out certain tags from rendering, and I believe that my expressions are not matching the tags properly, and is causing some articles to send an empty value to the dimension. I'm assuming because it found nothing that it's defaulting to page data?